# Android Download Manager Store/Show downloaded files in two directories

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I have used Android Download Manager for download Files from server as it's handles network error and resume downloading.

It's working fine, I can download files using this,

**Problem :** When I start downloading it's complete successfully and file is also downloaded once but it Store/Show the downloaded files in two directories one is **default download directory** of android phone and second is **custom directory** which created by me as i only want to Store/Show in my custom directory and then want to read only from that directory files.

**Question : how i only Store/Show downloaded files in custom created directory ??**

Below is the code which i used to download files using Download Manager.

```
public void downloadWithManager(String urlPath) {
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Demo");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(urlPath);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
    //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
    request.setTitle(tsLong.toString() + ".mp4");
    //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
    request.setDescription("Download in progress...");
    //Set the custom local destination for the downloaded file
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Demo", tsLong.toString() + ".mp4");
    //Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Of course you can ask DownloadManager to put a downloaded file in a specific folder and with a specific name. Examples are many on the internet.

Comment: And if you want to show them in your app you know in which folder you have to look. I do not understand your problem doing so.

Comment: @greenapps : im already making 1 directory folder with name "Demo" and downloaded files aslo store/show in that folder but this files also displays in default download folder too.

Comment: i don't want to show/store this files in default download folder because whenever user delete this files from default folder its deleted from our custom folder too.

Comment: Where does it display twice? You should look with a file explorer app in the usual 'Downloads' directory for that. Are you stating that if you ask DownloadManager to download a file to a specific folder "Demo" that it saves the file twice?

Comment: @greenapps : Not twice, display the same file with different folder one is at usual Download folder that you are telling and another which i have created "Demo" folder

Comment: WHERE DOES IT DISPLAY? Which app are you talking about? I asked you to use a file explorer app to look in both directories.

Comment: yes im using file explorer

Comment: but i dont want to display it in default download folder !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117937/discussion-between-uttam-panchasara-and-greenapps).

Comment: If you find that file in two directories with ES File Explorer than DownloadManager did put it in two directories isn't it? Why did you say 'Not twice' then?

Comment: i try to say tht same file display in two directories

Comment: Why are you talking about display? I want to know if the downloaded file is in two directories. If so then the file is downloaded twice. Or downloaded once but saved twice. So clear this up please.

Comment: File is downloaded only once.

Comment: Sorry i have no idea where you are talking about. Who is talking about references and deleting?  If you only would start answering my simple question.

Comment: `File is downloaded only once.`. And saved twice? To two different directories?

Comment: yes..  `Downloaded only once correct` but referring in two directories.

Comment: What is 'referring'? Who? Where? In which app? I want to know if the file IS in those two directories. Use ES File Explorer to check. And tell what you mean with referring? You are so unclear!

Comment: Means showing in two directories.